# React/Redux - Scrolling a div after page has been server-side rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, isomorphic-javascript

I have an application which uses server side rendering in React and Redux.

In the application there is a Grid of information which is wrapped inside a `div` tag. I have attached to it a `'ref'` attribute in order to manipulate the scrollbar of that particular `div`.

```
  render(){
    this.gridPosition()
    return (
      <div className='m_wrap' ref="scrollbars">
        <TimeBar/>
        <ChannelInfo info={this.props} />
      </div>
    )
  }
```

And gridPosition is:

```
  gridPosition(){
    if (this.props.slidePos == "Morning"){
      this.refs.scrollbars.scrollLeft = 0;
    } else if (this.props.slidePos == "Afternoon") {
      this.refs.scrollbars.scrollLeft = 2880;
    } else if (this.props.slidePos == "Evening") {
      this.refs.scrollbars.scrollLeft = 5280;
    } else if (this.props.slidePos == "Night") {
      this.refs.scrollbars.scrollLeft = 7200;
    }
  }
```

So the position of the scrollbar is determined by `this.props.slidePos`

This works when the application is loaded however it won't set the correct position on the initial render.

I have tried firing off an action in the `componentDidMount()` function but the `div` tag doesn't seem to be connected to the application after the server render.

If anyone could shed some light on this or point me in the right direction to resolve it I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Altering your scroll position inside `componentDidMount` is the right way to do it. Event when you receive initial html rendered on server-side React *will* render your app (`ReactDOM.render(....)` is still here and being called) at client-side and will compare resulting checksums. If they will not match React will replace received DOM with just rendered one.

Your `div.scrollbars` *will* be available in `refs` by the time of `componentDidMount` invocation. It will not only in case it was not part of your components hierarchy, i.e. it was not rendered. You can see working example showing scrolling server-rendered content [here](https://jsbin.com/fisilax/edit?html,css,js,output).

In general case your first code snipped where you call `this.gridPosition()` from `render` function should actually fall with exception, because by the time `gridPosition` is accessing `this.refs.scrollbars` it have not been created yet by `render` method. The only chance this code is working is because first render of your Component happens with the value of `this.props.slidePos` not matching any of listed in `gridPosition`.

Also please not, that using `String Refs` is [deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs).